# How do i generate signatures in benchmarking.rs?

Tags: benchmarking, signing

I am trying to generate an sr25519 signature within benchmarks. But i am facing an error that doesn't make sense to me.
`let sig: T::Signature = acc_pair.sign(&schema.encode()); |                  ------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found struct sp_core::sr25519::Signature`

Below is the definition of my type in the config trait:

```
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {

        type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;

        type Public: IdentifyAccount<AccountId = Self::AccountId> + Encode + Decode + Member + TypeInfo;

        type Signature: Verify<Signer = Self::Public> + Member + Parameter + Decode + Encode + TypeInfo;
}
```

How can i correctly create signatures in benchmarks? An explanation of where am going wrong will be appreciated. Unfortunately i can't share the code. You can share an example of a signature generated in benchmarks based on the defined signature type in the Config trait

Comment: Could you share the code link?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't share the code link but you can share an example of a signature generated in benchmarks that conforms to the Signature type  defined in the config trait.